# What are the sections in Qt's MOC generated .cpp file?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

Can someone please explain the sections in the file and their significance? How are signals and slots made available for calling?

Comment: You should post here a short example of generated cpp file and your thoughts about it's parts.

Answer (score 1):

A part of [Qt in Depth](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/learning/online/talks/archive/developerdays2006/qt-in-depth) talk from Qt DevDays 2006 is devoted to signal/slot internals.